# Accessing Keycloak-Service inside Docker by its Network Alias

Tags: docker, networking, jwt, keycloak, open-liberty

## Scenario

I have secured webservice (JakartaEE + Microprofile + JWT) running in open liberty. As issuer of the jwt token I use keycloak. For testing and development i want to run both services in docker. Therefore I wrote a docker-compose file. As test client I use JUnit with microprofile-client. This is running outside of docker.

## Problem

I can retrieve the JWT-Token via localhost at the host - e.g.:

```
POST /auth/realms/DC/protocol/openid-connect/token HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8080
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

realm=DC&grant_type=password&client_id=dc&username=dc_editor&password=******
```

The problem is, that from the perspective of the webservice localhost isn't the keycloak server. The JWT-Token-Validation against the issuer fails.

## Goal

I want to access the keycloak server from the host with its docker-internal network alias - e.g. `dcAuthServer`. The JWT-Token would be validated correctly.

## Code

The docker-compose file looks like this:

```
version: "3.8"
services:
  dcWebservice:
    environment:
      - DC_AUTH_SERVER_HOST=dcAuthServer
      - DC_AUTH_SERVER_PORT=8080
      - DC_AUTH_SERVER_REALM=DC
    image: dc_webservice:latest
    ports:
    - "9080:9080"
    networks:
      - dcNetwork

  dcAuthServer:
    image: dc_keycloak:latest
    ports:
    - "8080:8080"
    networks:
      dcNetwork:
        aliases:
            - dcAuthServer
    healthcheck:
      test: "curl --fail http://localhost:8080/auth/realms/DC || false"

networks:
  dcNetwork:
```

The environment `DC_AUTH*` are used in the mpJwt-configuration in `server.xml` of the open liberty server:

```xml
<mpJwt id="dcMPJWT" audiences="dc" issuer="http://${DC_AUTH_SERVER_HOST}:${DC_AUTH_SERVER_PORT}/auth/realms/${DC_AUTH_SERVER_REALM}"
           jwksUri="http://${DC_AUTH_SERVER_HOST}:${DC_AUTH_SERVER_PORT}/auth/realms/${DC_AUTH_SERVER_REALM}/protocol/openid-connect/certs"/>
```

The `issuer` is where I have to put a trusted issuer for the JWT-Token.

I hope I did not forget important information - just ask!

Thanks in advance
Robert

Comment: Do you require keycloak to be the JWT provider in your tests? For this situation in OpenLiberty I would utilize Microshed Testing which has auto-config for the JWT on the client/server side but still runs your liberty app in a docker container. See https://microshed.org/microshed-testing/features/MP_JWT.html and https://openliberty.io/guides/microshed-testing.html

Comment: Hi @AndyGuibert .. thanks for your hint. It was quiet easy to migrate to Microshed because I was using [Testcontainers](https://www.testcontainers.org) already. With Microshed I got rid of the manual setup of the MP-Client+JWT. Now its injected - thanks again. I leave the question open out of pure curiosity if there is a solution.

Comment: glad microshed worked for you. If you have ideas/suggestions for how Microshed could integrate with Keycloak containers directly, please file an issue on the Microshed github repo: https://github.com/MicroShed/microshed-testing

Comment: Hey, I'm having the same issue, and looking for solution. Did you able to resolve it?

Comment: Hi @Kostanos . I'm sorry, but I could not solve the problem as intended. I went on with the solution hinted by (at)AndyGuibert .. so everything was running inside a docker compose bubble and the services could see eachother by theire servicen names.